# PHP SUM function

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like following:

```
id    q_id         value  
------------------------
1     2            5 
2     2            NULL 
3     2            5 
4     2            NULL 
5     4            2 
6     4            NULL 
7     4            2 
8     4            NULL
```

What I want is to get the sum of (for example) all value `where q_id = 2`

```
    $sq = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(value) AS sum FROM  table WHERE q_id = 2)or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sq)){
    $sum = $row['sum'];
     }
  echo $sum."<br>";
```

But I'm getting

```
5
5
```

But what I want is the sum of the value and expecting 10 instead.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are [in the deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: where's the "GROUP BY" ?

Comment: The code you posted contains syntax errors, and the query you showed will not produce the result you indicated.  I don't think you're actually doing what you're showing us.

Comment: @Dagon: Not required here, as is filtered by `q_id` in the `WHERE` clause and MySQL will group all records together if an aggregate function is used without `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @eggyal golly, i thought it was compulsory for all the aggregate functions, thanks for the info

Comment: @Dagon: True of ANSI SQL, but see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html: "*If you use a group function in a statement containing no `GROUP BY` clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.*"

Comment: funny that the page heading is "*GROUP BY* (Aggregate) Functions"

Comment: There is indeed nothing wrong with the SQL as written in the question. I've spent too long working with Oracle I think, so I'd forgotten those details about MySQL's handling of GROUP BY and NULLs. I've tested the SQL and it produces 10. In order to debug I would suggest printing out the entire $row array in the loop to see its structure.

Comment: Also, you're only printing out the variable once - outside the while loop. And the variable can not in any way be getting the value "5\n5" here. So I agree with @GavinTowey in that there's really no way the code you posted can produce the output you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to loop over the result set anyway, why not just use

`SELECT value FROM table WHERE q_id=2`

then sum up those values using the while loop? Something like:

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sq)) {
    $sum += $row['value'];
}
echo $sum."<br>";`

Edit: also, as Jason McCreary said above, you should look into an alternate method of querying the database. I would suggest searching php.net for "PDO", which is very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

We can directly sum in the query like

```
SELECT 5+6 AS addition
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try... You are displaying `value`, there was missing quote in your code.

```
   $sq = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(value) AS sum FROM  `table` WHERE `q_id` = '2'")or die(mysql_error());

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sq))
   {
     $sum = $row["sum"];
   }

   echo $sum . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sq="SELECT  value FROM table WHERE q_id='".$am."'"; 
 $result=mysqli_query($link,$sq); 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
 $sum += $row['value']; 
     } 
 echo "<p>Sum:&nbsp;".$sum."</p><br>";
 //$am ='2'; 
 //$link  -- connection to the data base
```

Please put `$am ='2';` before the select statement and also make sure you have connected to the data base using `$link`

You will get the total sum according to the value of  `q_id`

I have tested the code and works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a GROUP BY to your query. Add the following to the end

```
GROUP BY q_id
```

Comment: Maybe - remove group by? He already gets result like it has a group by and want an opposite result

Comment: This is not needed on MySQL in the presence of `WHERE q_id = 2`.

Comment: does any one read the comments before posting their answer ? :-)

Comment: @Dagon: In fairness, this was posted around the same time as your original comment.

Comment: Thank you all guys but still the same problem even with GROUP BY q_id.