# GROUP BY id is working only in my MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on one of my old php projects where I used **GROUP BY head_id** that was working fine, but now it's showing nothing but blank page while executing. Showing results while I am trying **GROUP BY id** instead of **head_id** or anything else.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $start = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['start']);
  $end = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['end']);

  $sql = "SELECT *
  FROM bill_info
  WHERE date(updated_on) BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND is_paid='1'
  GROUP BY head_id";
  $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

}


while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
  echo $data['head_id']." - ".$data['amount'];
}
```

Only if I am trying to **GROUP BY id** then it's working fine but showing nothing while trying to **GROUP BY head_id**. There are lots of rows for same head_id, that's why I need to group them, otherwise report is becoming too long.

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||-----------------------------------------------------------
**Updated !!!** ---------------------------------------------------------
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

The query given below is working fine for me.

*$sql = "SELECT head_id, sum(amount), sum(student_no)
  FROM bill_info
  WHERE date(updated_on) BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND is_paid='1'
  GROUP BY head_id";*

I have tried to select other columns except head_id or aggregate function, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP SUM function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271598/php-sum-function)

Comment: whats your output? `while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
  echo $data['head_id']." - ".$data[sum(amount)];
}`

Comment: Your query is invalid because it aggregates by `head_id` but then also selects other non aggregate columns.  Also, you should look into using [prepared statements in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @VikasKatariya Showing nothing but blank page only, no errors also!!!

Comment: echo $res; what will be output?

Comment: You need to check the errors being returned from your MySQLi calls. You will almost certainly find that @TimBiegeleisen explanation is the correct one once you look at the actual mysqli error message.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $start = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['start']);
  $end = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['end']);

  $sql = "SELECT id, head_id, is_paid, amount, sum(student_no), sum(amount) AS sum
  FROM bill_info
  WHERE updated_on>='$start'
  AND updated_on<='$end'
  GROUP BY id";
  $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

}


while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
  $sum = $row['sum'];
}
 echo $sum."<br>";
```

Comment: why this answer is downvote:?

Comment: It's showing results while changing 'GROUP BY head_id' to 'GROUP BY id'

Comment: yes i miss this.. can you get your answeR? (sum) good question select this answe.r

Comment: if this answer is helpful then accept this answer thank you

Comment: 'sum(amount) AS sum' and sum(amount) is acting same, but I need to GROUP BY head_id, it was working before, why now behaving like this??

Comment: Low quality question. Low quality answer. `$sql` invalid in the question and in the answer. `ID column` seems to has unique values, which makes `group by` useless and `sum()` value invalid as well.

Comment: please select this answer thank yop..

Comment: hahaha right Dude.

Comment: Can you please explain why $sql is invalid ?